# Postgres array json recent date

Tags: json, postgresql

i have a json array like this:

```json
[
  {
    "date": "26/11/2020 23:27",
    "note": "test1"
  },
  {
    "date": "22/11/2020 22:59",
    "note": "test2"
  },
  {
    "date": "18/11/2020 17:08",
    "note": "test3"
  }
]
```

I would like to take the element that has the most recent data.

My old query to get the first element was like that:

```
(notes\:\:json->0)\:\:json->>'note' as note,
(notes\:\:json->0)\:\:json->>'date' as date_note
```

Answer (score 3):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6127a0ad3a0c7b7636c93cf2d253e4a8)

```
SELECT 
    elem.value ->> 'date' as thedate,
    elem.value ->> 'note' as note
FROM t,
    json_array_elements(data) elem                                  -- 1 
WHERE id = 4123
ORDER BY to_timestamp(elem ->> 'date', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') DESC   -- 2
LIMIT 1                                                             -- 3
```

1. Extract all array elements into one row
2. Read datetime string from `date` field, convert into timestamp and use it to order all array elements with most recent timestamp first
3. Just return the very first (= most recent) array element.

Comment: Is there any way to change this query?select (tb.notes::json->0)::json->>'note' as note,
    (tb.notes::json->0)::json->>'date' as date_note
from table as tb where id = 4545

Comment: i need to directly extract the array with the most recent date

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9dce10bde19e66daa7282e33214044cc Of course. Just add the WHERE clause to filter the id and extract the elements from the value