# Filtering in Django against a JsonField which is a JsON Array with dates values in it

Tags: json, django, postgresql

I have a model in Django where there is a `JsonField` named `periodicity` which serialize in an Json Array like this:

```json
{
  "id_series": 12381,
  "country_name": "Central African Republic",
  "periodicity": [
    {
      "period": "monthly",
      "start_date": "2010-10-01",
      "end_date": "2018-10-01"
    },
    {
      "period": "weekly",
      "start_date": "2011-10-01",
      "end_date": "2018-01-01"
    }
  ]
},
{
...
}
```

So my aim is to filter and find the series that have not been updated in less than a certain date. For that I need to query on the `end_date` of the inner Json Array. What is the best way to do a filtering?

I have tried casting the `end_date` to a date object by doing this :

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL
Serie.objects.annotate(endDate=RawSQL("((periodicity->>'end_date')::date)", [])).filter(endDate__gte=comparisonDate)
```

But so far it has not produced any result. I am looking into something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65184218/2219080.

Answer (score 0):

The similar logic might be used in order the extract the elements of the `periodicity` array through `JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS()` function and filtering out through `TO_DATE()` casting such as

```
SELECT t.jsdata ->> 'id_series' AS id_series, 
       t.jsdata ->> 'country_name' AS country_name,
       j.value ->> 'period' AS period
  FROM t,
       JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(jsdata->'periodicity') AS j
 WHERE TO_DATE(j.value->>'end_date','YYYY-MM-DD') >=  '2018-01-01'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=baf5dc841843c9b3c0489c0409e11765)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks you. I'll try it out soon and let you know.